# PIM NoClassDefFoundError but the jar is in the classpath

Tags: java-me, classpath, jsr75

I am implementing the PIM API in my J2ME app when I run it on the KEmulator or on the device (Sony Ericsson k800i) I am getting this exception

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/microedition/pim/PIMException
```

though the jar file has the PIMException.class file inside the javax/microedition/pim package.

Comment: `javax.microedition` classes don't get deployed to target device along with your code due to Java ME security architecture. Target device must support the respective API in order for your application to run. From what you describe, it looks like this isn't the case for KEmulator and Sony Ericsson k800i, check their manuals

Comment: Well the problem is solved, all i needed to do is add the JSR api as refrence library, thanx for ur quick reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the problem is solved, all i needed to do is add the JSR api as refrence library.